# Mapping native C structure to JNA

Tags: jna

Very long post...

I have the following C structs that I've mapped into JNA.
These structures are used on Windows to get the raw input, from mouse, keyboard and other HID devices.
The problem is that I don't get anything in the RAWINPUT.data.keyboard (RAWKEYBAORD) structure. I haven't tested with mouse yet.

Regarding the RAWMOUSE structure, it's been modified after technomage's previous comments.

But I don't get any data in the field I expected, when debugging I can see there are data. 
I think I might have mapped the structs incorrectly, or doing something wrong in the usage of them.
Can someone tell me if my mapping is correct or can use some corrections ?

I've written a DLL in C code previously, which I used in Java using JNI.
But I rather loose the DLL and use Java.

The two method below are mapped like this:
C code:

```
UINT WINAPI GetRawInputData(
  _In_       HRAWINPUT hRawInput,
  _In_       UINT uiCommand,
  _Out_opt_  LPVOID pData,
  _Inout_    PUINT pcbSize,
  _In_       UINT cbSizeHeader
);
```

Java code:

```
int GetRawInputData(RawInputLibrary.HRAWINPUT hRawInput, int uiCommand, Memory pData, IntByReference pcbSize, int cbSizeHeader);
```

C code:

```
BOOL WINAPI RegisterRawInputDevices(
  _In_  PCRAWINPUTDEVICE pRawInputDevices,
  _In_  UINT uiNumDevices,
  _In_  UINT cbSize
);
```

Java Code

```
boolean RegisterRawInputDevices(RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTDEVICE pRawInputDevices, int uiNumDevices, int cbSize);
```

When I dump the buffer I can see the following the value for the key pressed.The 42, in memory block 6, is the letter b pressed on the keyboard, and that value changes according to the key I press. Here is the dump of the RAWINPUT structure:

```
RawInputLibrary$RAWINPUT(allocated@0x525ecb8 (44 bytes) (shared from allocated@0x525ecb8 (44 bytes))) {
  RawInputLibrary$RAWINPUTHEADER header@0=RawInputLibrary$RAWINPUTHEADER(allocated@0x525ecb8 (16 bytes) (shared from allocated@0x525ecb8 (44 bytes) (shared from allocated@0x525ecb8 (44 bytes)))) {
    int dwType@0=1
    int dwSize@4=20
    WinNT$HANDLE hDevice@8=native@0x3da0cb3 (com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLE@3da0cb3)
    WinDef$WPARAM wParam@c=1
  }
  RawInputLibrary$RAWINPUT$DataUnion data@10=RawInputLibrary$RAWINPUT$DataUnion(allocated@0x525ecc8 (28 bytes) (shared from allocated@0x525ecb8 (44 bytes) (shared from allocated@0x525ecb8 (44 bytes)))) {
    RawInputLibrary$RAWMOUSE mouse@0=RawInputLibrary$RAWMOUSE(auto-allocated@0x525ed48 (28 bytes)) {
      short usFlags@0=0
      NativeLong ulButtons@4=0
      short usButtonFlags@8=0
      short usButtonData@a=0
      NativeLong ulRawButtons@c=0
      NativeLong lLastX@10=0
      NativeLong lLastY@14=0
      NativeLong ulExtraInformation@18=0
    }
    RawInputLibrary$RAWKEYBOARD keyboard@0=RawInputLibrary$RAWKEYBOARD(auto-allocated@0x525ed70 (16 bytes)) {
      short MakeCode@0=0
      short Flags@2=0
      short Reserved@4=0
      short VKey@6=0
      int Message@8=0
      NativeLong ExtraInformation@c=0
    }
    RawInputLibrary$RAWHID hid@0=RawInputLibrary$RAWHID(auto-allocated@0x525ed88 (12 bytes)) {
      int dwSizeHid@0=0
      int dwCount@4=0
      byte bRawData[1]@8=[B@50fe39
    }
  }
}
memory dump
[01000000]
[20000000]
[b30cda03]
[01000000]
[30000000]
[00004200]
[00010000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
```

These are the structs I've mapped. The C counter part can be seen here (not posting them in order to keep the post smaller): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468899(v=vs.85).aspx

```
public static class HRAWINPUT extends PointerType {
    public HRAWINPUT(Pointer address) {
        super(address);
    }
    public HRAWINPUT() {
        super();
    }
}

public class RAWINPUT extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends RAWINPUT implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public static class ByValue extends RAWINPUT implements Structure.ByValue {}

        public RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTHEADER   header;
        public DataUnion                                            data;

        public static class DataUnion extends Union {
            public static class ByReference extends DataUnion implements Structure.ByReference {}
            public static class ByValue extends DataUnion implements Structure.ByValue {}

            public RawInputLibrary.RAWMOUSE mouse;
            public RawInputLibrary.RAWKEYBOARD keyboard;

            public RawInputLibrary.RAWHID hid;
            public DataUnion() {
                super();
            }

            public DataUnion(RawInputLibrary.RAWMOUSE mouse) {
                super();
                this.mouse = mouse;
                setType(RawInputLibrary.RAWMOUSE.class);
            }

            public DataUnion(RawInputLibrary.RAWKEYBOARD keyboard) {
                super();
                this.keyboard = keyboard;
                setType(RawInputLibrary.RAWKEYBOARD.class);
            }

            public DataUnion(RawInputLibrary.RAWHID hid) {
                super();
                this.hid = hid;
                setType(RawInputLibrary.RAWHID.class);
            }

            protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
                return Arrays.asList("mouse", "keyboard", "hid");
            }
        }

        public RAWINPUT() {
            super();
        }

        public RAWINPUT(Pointer p) {
            super(p);
            useMemory(p); //using this doesn't make any difference, but maybe I need to do something similar to this in the data struct ?
            read();
        }

        public RAWINPUT(RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTHEADER header, DataUnion data) {
            super();
            this.header = header;
            this.data = data;
        }

        protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("header", "data");
        }
    }

    public static class RAWINPUTHEADER extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends RAWINPUTHEADER implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public static class ByValue extends RAWINPUTHEADER implements Structure.ByValue {}

        public int                          dwType;
        public int                          dwSize;

        public WinNT.HANDLE         hDevice;
        public WinDef.WPARAM    wParam;

        public RAWINPUTHEADER() {
            super();
        }

        public RAWINPUTHEADER(int dwType, int dwSize, WinNT.HANDLE hDevice, WinDef.WPARAM wParam) {
            super();
            this.dwType = dwType;
            this.dwSize = dwSize;
            this.hDevice = hDevice;
            this.wParam = wParam;
        }

        protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("dwType", "dwSize", "hDevice", "wParam");
        }
    }

    public static class RAWHID extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends RAWHID implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public static class ByValue extends RAWHID implements Structure.ByValue {}

        public          int dwSizeHid;
        public          int dwCount;
        public byte[]   bRawData = new byte[1];

        public RAWHID() {
            super();
        }

        public RAWHID(int dwSizeHid, int dwCount, byte bRawData[]) {
            super();
            this.dwSizeHid = dwSizeHid;
            this.dwCount = dwCount;

            if ((bRawData.length != this.bRawData.length)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong array size !");
            }
            this.bRawData = bRawData;
        }

        protected List<? > getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("dwSizeHid", "dwCount", "bRawData");
        }
    }

    public static class RAWKEYBOARD extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends RAWKEYBOARD implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public static class ByValue extends RAWKEYBOARD implements Structure.ByValue {}

        public short            MakeCode;
        public short            Flags;
        public short            Reserved;
        public short            VKey;
        public int                  Message;
        public NativeLong   ExtraInformation;

        public RAWKEYBOARD() {
            super();
        }

        public RAWKEYBOARD(short MakeCode, short Flags, short Reserved, short VKey, int Message, NativeLong ExtraInformation) {
            super();
            this.MakeCode = MakeCode;
            this.Flags = Flags;
            this.Reserved = Reserved;
            this.VKey = VKey;
            this.Message = Message;
            this.ExtraInformation = ExtraInformation;
        }

        protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("MakeCode", "Flags", "Reserved", "VKey", "Message", "ExtraInformation");
        }

    }

    public static class RAWMOUSE extends Structure {
        public static class ByReference extends RAWMOUSE implements Structure.ByReference {}
        public static class ByValue extends RAWMOUSE implements Structure.ByValue {}

        public short                usFlags;
        public NativeLong       ulButtons;

        public short                usButtonFlags;
        public short                usButtonData;

        public NativeLong       ulRawButtons;
        public NativeLong       lLastX;
        public NativeLong       lLastY;
        public NativeLong       ulExtraInformation;

        public RAWMOUSE() {
            super();
        }

        public RAWMOUSE(short usFlags, NativeLong ulButtons, short usButtonFlags, short usButtonData, NativeLong ulRawButtons, NativeLong lLastX, NativeLong lLastY, NativeLong ulExtraInformation) {
            super();
            this.usFlags = usFlags;
            this.ulButtons = ulButtons;
            this.usButtonFlags = usButtonFlags;
            this.usButtonData = usButtonData;
            this.ulRawButtons = ulRawButtons;
            this.lLastX = lLastX;
            this.lLastY = lLastY;
            this.ulExtraInformation = ulExtraInformation;
        }

        protected List<?> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("usFlags", "ulButtons", "usButtonFlags", "usButtonData", "ulRawButtons", "lLastX", "lLastY", "ulExtraInformation");
        }
    }
```

The code below is an extract of thew code I'm using to test.

```
private class WndProc implements User32.WindowProc {
    public WndProc() {
    }

    @Override
    public LRESULT callback(HWND hwnd, int msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
        switch (msg) {
            case User32.WM_CREATE: {
                if (hwnd != null) {
                    log.debug("Registering raw input device notifications...");
                    RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTDEVICE.ByReference rawInputDevice = new RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTDEVICE.ByReference();

                    //create an array of the struct in memory and fill it with data, and then parse the reference to the native call
                    RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTDEVICE[] pRawInputDevice = (RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTDEVICE[]) rawInputDevice.toArray(1);

                    pRawInputDevice[0].dwFlags = RawInputLibrary.RIDEV_INPUTSINK;       // receive system wide keystrokes
                    pRawInputDevice[0].usUsagePage = 1;                                             // generic desktop controls
                    pRawInputDevice[0].usUsage = 6;                                                     // keyboard
                    pRawInputDevice[0].hwndTarget = hwnd;

                    // register interest in raw data input
                    if (!rawInputLib.RegisterRawInputDevices(rawInputDevice, 1, rawInputDevice.size())) {
                        rawInputRegistrationSuccess = false;
                        log.error("Failed to register for raw input messages");
                    } else {
                        log.debug("Done registering raw input device notifications...");
                    }
                } else {
                    log.debug("window handle is not defined");
                }
                break;
            }
            case RawInputLibrary.WM_INPUT: {
                log.debug("Got raw input device message...");

                IntByReference dwSize = new IntByReference();
                int rawInputHeaderSize = new RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUTHEADER().size();
                RawInputLibrary.HRAWINPUT hRawInput = new RawInputLibrary.HRAWINPUT(lparam.toPointer());

                if (rawInputLib.GetRawInputData(hRawInput, RawInputLibrary.RID_INPUT, null, dwSize, rawInputHeaderSize) < 0) {
                    break;
                }

                if (dwSize.getValue() == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                IntByReference bufferSize = new IntByReference(Math.max(dwSize.getValue(), new RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUT().size()));
                Memory buffer = new Memory(bufferSize.getValue());
                if (rawInputLib.GetRawInputData(hRawInput, RawInputLibrary.RID_INPUT, buffer, bufferSize, rawInputHeaderSize) == -1) {
                    buffer.clear();
                    break;
                }

                RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUT rawinput = new RawInputLibrary.RAWINPUT(buffer);
                int event = rawinput.data.keyboard.Message;
                switch(event) {
                    case User32.WM_KEYDOWN:
                    case User32.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                        log.debug("Got raw input keyboard pressed");
                        switch(rawinput.data.keyboard.VKey){
                            //Shift
                            case 160:
                            case 161:
                                // inform listener about shift key pressed
                                break;

                            //Ignore special characters
                            case 144: //Numlock
                                break;

                            default:
                                // inform listener about key pressed
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case User32.WM_KEYUP:
                    case User32.WM_SYSKEYUP:
                        if (rawinput.data.keyboard.VKey == 160 || rawinput.data.keyboard.VKey == 161) {
                            // inform listener about shift key released
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
            default : {
                return user32Lib.DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
            }
        }
        return new LRESULT(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You really should include details about how you're using these data structures, as well as any data you've accumulated thus far.

Comment: Nominally, your mapping is correct.  Personally I'd forego the union and just use one of the fields and provide the other as a derived property.  Code would be much simpler.

Comment: To me it look like the memory dump show that the offset doesn't match the structure. It looks like the first 16 byte, the header, is correct. But then the keyboard structure (16 bytes) comes, instead of the mouse structure. But why I don't know. Pretty much the same implementation works when its done in C.

Comment: Changing the order of the mouse and keyboard structs doesn't change a thing, except the order. They are still not populated and the as expected the memory layout is the same.

Comment: If you're going to inline the mouse buttons union, you need to use one or the other of the union fields, not both (`ulButtons` vs `ulButtonFlags` + `ulButtonData`).

Comment: Union fields occupy the same memory location; if you have three union fields and the union's address is 0x100, all three fields will map to that address.

Comment: I'd also recommend providing a `Pointer`-based constructor for each of your unions and structs.  This avoids superfluous memory allocation.

Comment: Hi Technomage. I did thr changes you mentioned, and I don't know why I forgot that unions share the same memory space. After I changes code to handle it that way (using pointer, setting type and calling read) everything then worked like a charm. Many many thanks for your help and the JNA AIP :-)